# Getting a template to apply a class to a span based on conditional results of passed in parameters

Tags: xslt-1.0

This is only a test script and I can supply a two test XML data blocks if required.

The script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msa="http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/msa">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
    doctype-public="//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>

  <xsl:variable name="PubDB" select="document('MSA_PublisherDatabase.XML')"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <title>Test</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting">
          <xsl:call-template name="IsAvailableMidweek">
            <xsl:with-param name="strName" select="Chairman"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="IsAvailableMidweek">
    <xsl:param name="strName"/>
    <xsl:variable name="thePublisher" select="$PubDB/msa:PublisherDatabase/msa:Publishers/msa:Publisher[msa:Name=$strName]"/>
    <xsl:if test="$thePublisher">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$thePublisher/msa:Availability/@Midweek='false'">
          <p>Not available @Midweek</p>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:variable name ="datMonth" select="format-number(MeetingDate/@Month,'00')"/>
          <xsl:variable name ="datDay" select="format-number(MeetingDate/@Day,'00')"/>
          <xsl:variable name="datMeeting" select="concat(MeetingDate/@Year, '-', $datMonth, '-', $datDay)"/>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$thePublisher/msa:Availability/msa:DatesNotAvailable[msa:Date=$datMeeting]">
              <p>
                <xsl:text>Not available for date </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$datMeeting"/>
              </p>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <p>Available</p>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have been working on the `IsAvailableMidweek` template and in principle it works. The content it displays was for debugging purposes.

The challenge I have is that I want to display (this this specific case) the Chairman in a `span` as text. If he is determined as "Not Available" then I want to apply a class of `NotAvailable` to the `span` object.

I know how to display the value in a `span`. That is straightforward. But how do I adjust the template `IsAvailableMidweek` I have written so that it can apply this class if it determines the person is not available?

I hope this makes sense. I don't think I can use functions in with XSLT-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way, but it appears to do what I am looking for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msa="http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/msa">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
    doctype-public="//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>

  <xsl:variable name="PubDB" select="document('MSA_PublisherDatabase.XML')"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <title>Test</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting">
          <p>
            <xsl:call-template name="SetClassName">
              <xsl:with-param name="strName" select="Chairman"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:value-of select="Chairman"/>
          </p>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="SetClassName">
    <xsl:param name="strName"/>
    <xsl:variable name="thePublisher" select="$PubDB/msa:PublisherDatabase/msa:Publishers/msa:Publisher[msa:Name=$strName]"/>
    <xsl:if test="$thePublisher">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$thePublisher/msa:Availability/@Midweek='false'">
          <xsl:attribute name="class">NotAvailable</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:variable name ="datMonth" select="format-number(MeetingDate/@Month,'00')"/>
          <xsl:variable name ="datDay" select="format-number(MeetingDate/@Day,'00')"/>
          <xsl:variable name="datMeeting" select="concat(MeetingDate/@Year, '-', $datMonth, '-', $datDay)"/>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$thePublisher/msa:Availability/msa:DatesNotAvailable[msa:Date=$datMeeting]">
              <xsl:attribute name="class">NotAvailable</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <!-- Available — Do Further Tests -->
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```